# Solutions to sum of exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I am reading a paper where the authors state that there exist infinite solutions to

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sin(m\pi a_n)}{m\pi}e^{-im\pi(2b_n+a_n)}=0, m\in\mathbb{Z}, m\neq0
$$

where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are between $0$ and $1$. I have spent lots of time figuring out how the solutions, i.e., $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s, look like for this problem but I have failed to proceed. I was hoping I could find some advice on this here.

Comment: So do we sum over `n` or `m`, or is the `m` a typo?

Comment: @kvantour The summation is over $n$. Also, $m$ is any non-zero integer. The edited question does not have a typo.

Comment: So the division of $m\pi$ is just confusing

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer but too long for a comment.**

Suppose $a_1=\ldots = a_N=\frac{1}{2}$, then we see that the sum is
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\frac{\pi m}{2}}{m\pi}e^{-im\pi/2}\sum^N_{n=1}e^{-i2\pi mb_n}.
\end{align}
If $m$ is even then any thing will work, i.e. the sum will be zero (not in a very interesting way). If $m$ is odd then, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\frac{\pi (2k+1)}{2}}{(2k+1)\pi}e^{-i(2k+1)\pi/2} = \frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi i}\ne 0
\end{align}
which means that the sum is zero if
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{n=1}e^{-i2\pi mb_n}=0
\end{align}
which means that $e^{-i2\pi mb_n}$ are the $N$th roots of unity (and any rotation of them).